# R Studio editData errormsg = object ‘datatables html’ not found

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am making a loop that allows the correlation matrix to be edited until the matrix is positive definite. If I run the steps individually without the loop it works. But using the loop I get an error. I’ve done a lot of googling and can’t figure out the problem. I am using the `editData` library.

```
repeat{
   corr3 <- nearPD(corr, corr=TRUE, do2eigen=TRUE)
   corr3 <- as.matrix(corr3[["mat"]]) #pull the matrix from the list corr3
   numrows <- nrow(corr3)
   numcols <- ncol(corr3)
   corr <- round(corr,7)
   corr4 <- round(corr3,7)
   rownames(corr) <- rownames(corr3)
   #colnames(corr3) <- colnames(corr)
   if(identical(corr,corr4)) {break}
   else {
     corr3 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(corr3)) #change to data frame so matrix can be edited
     corr7 <- editData(corr3)
     corr8 <- matrix(unlist(corr7), nrow=numrows, byrow=T)
     corr9 <- mapply(corr8, FUN=as.numeric)
     corr9 <- matrix(data=corr9, ncol=numcols, nrow=numrows)
     corr9 <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(corr9))
     colnames(corr9) <- NULL
     corr <- corr9
   }  
}
```

Output:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3948

03 Oct 2018 11:50:04 [rsession-default] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=object 'datatables_html' not found]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::exec::executeSafely(rstudio_boost::function<void()>) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:212; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::session::{anonymous}::processEvents() /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionHttpMethods.cpp:91

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3948
```

Answer (score 0):

same error after using editData in RStudio. This error started a few days ago (a couple of weeks?) but not before. Maybe some regression in editData code which shows up after upgrading system or r packagaes? (using Kubuntu 16.04 here, with rrutrer repo to get updated R packages)

```
if (my_data_file1!="NA") {
  md.1 <- gidFileRead(my_file1)
  md.1.orig <- md.1
  if (dim(md.1.orig)[1]!=0) {
    md.1 <- editData(md.1.orig)
  }
  md.1.esborrats <- setdiff(md.1.orig, md.1)
  if (dim(md.1)[1]==0) {
  md.1 <- rbind(md.1,
                rep("NA",length(md.1)))
  colnames(md.1) <- colnames(gidFileRead(my_file1))
  }
}
```